# Initials Profile Picture

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, controller, external-services

I am trying create a function to display the initials of the person (not the current user) if they don't have a profile picture. I have all the initials stored in a list in my page controller.

Can anyone give me an idea how to do this?

An example would be Skype. If the user "Michael Kevin" does not have any uploaded profile picture, it would make one with the initials "MK"

Thank you